# goobbe.com Clone site

Tags: discussion

Is this the place to report a clone site?  goobbe.com  Not only is it a clone but acts fairly dangerous.  Click link download kind of stuff.  Having made the mistake of clicking a google result.

The main reason for asking this question is as users do we ask questions like this here?  Are we just supposed to live with the attack of the clones that google is apparently to ignorant not to show in its result?

Comment: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)